# VMware Tools list of all installed files with it

Tags: vmware

I'm reversing an anti VMware mechanism which detects `VGAuthService.exe` and `vmtoolsd.exe` as well as a few registries that I've taken care of and some drivers from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\vm...`. I deleted `C:\Program Files\VMware` folder and those drivers, killed `VGAuthService.exe`, `vmtoolsd.exe` and `vm3dservice.exe` processes but it's still detected, which means I'm missing something. However, when I uninstall VMware Tools, even without rebooting the machine, it's undetected.

Is there a tool/or way to find which files VMware Tools installation drops on disk, what it modifies, etc.? I remember there was a tool "Orca" which was useful for .MSI files, but it's not in this case.

My VM:

```
VMware® Workstation 15 Pro
15.5.5 build-16285975
```

Comment: For registry changes you can use [RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html). Just make one snapshot, install VMWare tools and compare the registry afterwards. See also this question for more tools: https://serverfault.com/questions/11829/how-to-make-compare-filesystem-registry-snapshots-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it's checking for the drivers (e.g. network card, mouse, or display), or for a registered service (even if it's not running). Check the devices and services list before and after uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

First step in understanding installer is identifying what product the installer was created with, then look is there any known extract command lines. Tools such as [Universal Extractor 2](https://github.com/Bioruebe/UniExtract2) can also help do this automatically.
In this case if you use a tool such as [ProcMon](https://live.sysinternals.com/ProcMon.exe) you can see that VMWare's setup.exe extracts an MSI and executes that.

We can pass the [admin install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/administrative-installation) command line to setup.exe, which is then passed to Windows Installer msiexec.exe which extracts the MSI. This is also documented by VMWare in [Extracting the drivers from VMware Tools bundled with VMware Workstation](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2032184#:%7E:text=%20Extracting%20the%20drivers%20from%20VMware%20Tools%20bundled,the%20process%20is%20complete%2C%20click%20Fi...%20More%20)

```
setup /A /P C:\setup
```

This will output files into C:\setup along with the MSI.
You can then just browse the folder structure to identify files, or use an MSI editing tool such as [ORCA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe) open the MSI to view registry tables and custom actions.

Also be aware there is more low level options then simply looking for files/drivers to detect running in VMWare for example as per [Mechanisms to determine if software is running in a VMware virtual machine](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1009458#:%7E:text=Detecting%20when%20software%20is%20running%20in%20a%20VMware,hypervisor%20port%20Testing%20the%20CPUID%20hypervisor%20present%20bit)

- Testing the CPUID hypervisor present bit Testing the virtual BIOS
- DMI information and the hypervisor port

Example using CPU id:

```
int cpuid_check() {
    unsigned int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    char hyper_vendor_id[13];
    cpuid(0x1, & eax, & ebx, & ecx, & edx;;
        if (bit 31 of ecx is set) {
          cpuid(0x40000000, & eax, & ebx, & ecx, & edx;; memcpy(hyper_vendor_id + 0, & ebx, 4); memcpy(hyper_vendor_id + 4, & ecx, 4); memcpy(hyper_vendor_id + 8, & edx, 4); hyper_vendor_id[12] = '\0';
              if (!strcmp(hyper_vendor_id, "VMwareVMware")) return 1; // Success - running under VMware         }
```

Using DMI information:

```
int dmi_check(void) {
    char string[10];
    GET_BIOS_SERIAL(string);
    if (!memcmp(string, "VMware-", 7) || !memcmp(string, "VMW", 3)) return 1; // DMI contains VMware specific string.         else                 return 0; }
```

Comment: 7-Zip is also nice if you only want to get the files from MSI databases.